# Binormal vector, $B(t)$, is independent of $t$?

Tags: vectors, curvature

What does it mean that the binormal vector, $B(t)$, is independent of $t$?

Also, if the curvature, $k(t)$, of a curve equals $\frac{1}{t}$, where $t\ge 0$, does the curve posses any points in which the curvature is zero?

I know that the curvature will be undefined if $t=0$. Does it meant that the answer to the question is no?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're asking two questions here, one of which is stated only in the title. This is extremely confusing. Am I missing something?

Comment: One important consequence of a constant binormal vector is that the curve belongs to a fixed plane.

Comment: It seems to me what's *really* interesting is what happens as $t \to 0$!

Answer (score 1):

My instinct would be no since $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{t}=0$, but I do not know if you would be considering the long time behaviour, but in any case "$\infty$" is not a point